# Missing file references in TYPO3 backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, fal

In a TYPO3 6.2 site that was upgraded from 4.5, the "Ref" column in the file list doesn't provide accurate data.

For example, this image is definitively being used on a page, but the reference is not shown in the backend:

[image]

I have run the File Abstraction Layer: Update storage index task in the scheduler and updated the refindex several times - no change.

What can I do to make the references display correctly?

Comment: Is this image used as FAL image or it is just simply TCA 'group' with *internal_type* set to 'file' or 'file_reference'? In other words: is image used in standard fileds (like "Media" from page or in tt_content) or in custom extension?

Comment: It's used in a tt_content field, as FAL. But I now looked at it more closely - the image looks the same, but the one used is a copy that is actually in /fileadmin/_migrated/pics/ ! Is there a reason that they have landed there, and can I simply delete unused references and move used pics to the desired locations?

Comment: I also have an older pre-fal custom extension, where, as you say, the references are not displayed. Is there a way to see them?

Comment: afaik, image lands to '_migrated' folder only when it was somehow manipulated (e.g. width or height was adjusted). So, yes, yo can delete orifinal one, if no references are pointed to it.

Comment: As for a non-fal images - I believe, tehre is no way since 6.x to see references to them, because files are no longer files, but records in db, and only db references are reflected in "Filelist".

Comment: Thanks, Viktor! My question is solved. If you feel like, just post an answer below to accept

Comment: Enhanced my answer with more correct and full info =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclusion of comments to a question:

After a migration from pre-FAL installation (TYPO3 < 6.x) all used images, that were located in **/uploads/pics** or **/uploads/media** [are moved](https://wiki.typo3.org/File_Abstraction_Layer#fileadmin.2F_migrated.2F) to **/fileadmin/_migrated/** folder.

So, if your image in "Filelist" is reported as without references, then it means, that it *probably* is.

Be aware, that if you have extensions, which are **not FAL-aware**, then a file **still can be in use**, but no usage counter will be shown, becasue files are referenced not through FAL (db), but via filesystem.

At the moment of writing, I don't know any tool, that can help to migrate 'internal_type'=>'file' to FAL. If someone finds it, please, add it here in comments or as separate answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! It feels like the upgrade destroyed my whole image order, but actually, I realize that the previous behaviour of copying everything to /uploads/pics is the culprit